# How to use google analytic in my silverlight website?

Tags: silverlight, google-analytics, silverlight-5.0, google-analytics-api

I want to track all the events(like button clicked) and track the number of online users in my silverlight web application.
Can you please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Microsoft Silverlight Analytics Framework](http://msaf.codeplex.com/). It supports Google analytics along with variety of other analytics providers.